# What software lets me quickly browse and zoom images on a Mac?

Tags: software, macintosh

I am looking for an image viewer for mac with the following characteristics:

- Lightweight - loads fast
- Full screen mode
- Magnifier
- Can load a directory for browsing

Any suggestions?

(iPhoto 11 has a full screen mode, but no handy zooming capabilities for individual photos as far as I know)

Comment: have you tried preview

Comment: from the answers I got so far, I liked Xee and Simple Comic. the latter has a loupe, which is specially handy. regarding preview, the main limitation that I find is that zooming in full screen doesn't work very well - the only way I found to do it is the OS X's built in zooming feature which is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 11):

To be honest I just use preview if I want a quick run through of images

Answer (score 4):

Preview is a good option, but **you should consider Quick Look**, which offers almost everything you want, is built-in, and is available all the time.

It’s dead simple: Hit **`Command-A`** to select all the images in a folder, then **`Command-Option-Space`** to bring Quick Look up in full-screen mode. If you want to zoom in more, you can use the zoom feature which is built-in to Mac OS X: **While holding `Control`**, *scroll up* to zoom in, and *scroll down* to zoom out. You *may* need to enable zoom in Preferences; I don’t recall if it’s enabled by default. It’s simple enough: System Preferences -> Trackpad -> Screen Zoom.

Quick Look can show you one image at a time, and it also has an Index Sheet mode, which shows you thumbnails of all the images you selected. You can navigate with the arrow keys, or with the usual swipe gestures on your trackpad or mouse. It even works with RAWs. Give it a shot! I think you’ll be very pleased with what it can do.

Comment: But as far as I know the built in **zoom feature** you describe is more a magnifier. I think the magnifier will interpolate the pixels to **magnify the desktop/UI**, hence you will **not be able to use this feature to zoom in your image** i.e. 1:1 or 100% view.
I also use the Finder in Cover Flow mode to flick over images, just as a side note :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a similar kind of an app recently and the best light-weight software I could find was [**Xee**](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/xee.html).
It really fills the gap between the Quick Look and Capture One - the other image viewers I'm frequently using.

You could find more alternatives from the alternativeto.net website. I spotted Xee there.

Comment: -1 for Xee. I used to love it, then I discovered it does not color manage the images, so it's almost worthless for any photography workflow.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest preview. Its built in and the newer version (Leopard and up) is actually quite nice

Answer (score 2):

I've searched for something like this for a while as well and haven't found anything great. Depending on what I'm doing, I use a combination of:

- Picasa
- Preview
- Simple Comic (no really, you can page through a directory of images really easily, and has Loupe)
- ACDSee (beta) It's not lightweight, though has lots of features (http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/4678/acdsee-pro)

Seriously though, take a look at Simple Comic (http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/21987/simple-comic), it covers everything you asked for. If you keep it in your dock, you can just drag a directory icon onto it to view it (including subdirectories), keyboard shortcuts for fullscreen and image sizing, a Loupe magnifier, loads pretty quick, can view zip files. Best of all you can read comics with it as well. :)

Comment: Thanks. Simple Comic is not bad and is the kind of program I was looking for (the loupe is really handy) but needs more work from the developer. It's still a bit slow and buggy.

Answer (score 1):

After many searches and comparisons I settle to [XnViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/). Ultra fast, cross-platform, full of features, actively developed. And of course, free.

Answer (score 1):

Photo Mechanic is probably the fastest image browser you'll find. It's pretty much the standard among sports shooters that frequently shoot thousands of images.

Answer (score -1):

I turned the zoom feature on within the accessibility section of the System Preferences.....

Comment: Does that accomplish all the requirements of the question?